# Where is the error in this proof using induction?

Tags: induction, fake-proofs

We want to prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}t_{i}$ only if $t_i=x_i$. We use a proof by induction.

We check the first case: $\sum_{i=1}^{1} x_{i}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{1} x_{i}t_{i}$ only if $t_i=x_i$.

We assume by inductive hypothesis that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}t_{i}$ only if $t_i=x_i$.

We proceed to prove it for $n+1$.

We have that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x_{i}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^2 + x_{n+1}^{2}$$ and by inductive hypothesis that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}t_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^2$$ Therefore, $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x_{i}t_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^2 + x_{n+1}t_{n+1}$$ Then, if $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x_{i}^2 =\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x_{i}t_{i}$, we can substitute and operate to have  that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^2 + x_{n+1}^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^2 + x_{n+1}t_{n+1}$$ $$x_{n+1}^{2}=x_{n+1}t_{n+1}$$ $$x_{n+1}=t_{n+1}$$ As a result, we get that $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x_{i}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x_{i}t_{i}$ only if $t_i=x_i$, ending the proof.

However, the proved statement is not true. For instance, $$3^2+9^2=3*9+9*7$$

Why does the proof by induction fail?

Comment: Where do you think it fails?

Comment: It's already false for $n=2$, so study the logic that supposedly gets you from $n=1$ to $n=2$.  Note:  I can't follow your reasoning...why should $x_{n+1}^2=x_{n+1}t_{n+1}$?  In your example, it isn't true that $9^2=9\times 7$.

Comment: In the base case you need to assume $x_1 \neq 0$.  Same thing happens in the inductive step with $x_{n+1}$.  Otherwise, you can't cancel it.

Comment: With no further assumptions this is very clearly a false statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us assume that $x_n\neq 0\;\forall\; n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that we get at least a valid base case.

The main issue is that you do not use your inductive hypothesis
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_it_i \;\;\Longleftrightarrow \;\;
t_i = x_i\;\forall\; i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}
$$
but you use only the left side
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_it_i
$$
as an isolated statement. This statement is completely different from your original inductive hypothesis. You cannot derive $
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_it_i
$
from your inductive hypothesis.

Comment: now I see where it fails. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It seems the $n=1$ case isn't even true. If $x^2=xt$, that doesn't imply that $x=t$ (particularly if $x=0$).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).